# Rewritre friendly to old url and redirect old url to friendly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm rewritting this

`http://myweb.com/post/5/title-of-the-post` (new url)

To

`http://myweb.com/post.php?id=5` (old url)

I have achieved this by:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^post/(.+)/(.+) post.php?id=$2
```

But if I try to enter to the old url it's still possible, so how can I **redirect to the new one** and not end up in a loop?

Comment: ¿Where is the resource of the new URL, still `http://myweb.com/post.php?id=5`?

Comment: yes, the resource is the same. only turning it to friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^post\.php$ post/%1/article [R=301,L]
```

This will force an immediate redirection and will not process any further rules. Requests to post/what/ever won't match this rule and skip on by. Note you have to create a generic article title, as .htaccess has no way of knowing the title to use.

Next, add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Requests to post.php will have already been caught above, so they won't reach this line. This will do the redirection as expected and you should not have the endless loop.